# Onenote for windows 10 doesn't have "File" tab

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-onenote

I was trying to change the default file location of onenote notebook.

According to [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/change-the-default-storage-location-for-backup-files-2a35f601-cbc2-46cf-928a-1f30316fb009) help page, I need to go to file tab to change the setting. However I couldn't find the file tab anywhere as shown below.

[image: My onenote UI]

Comment: Try using the Desktop version of OneNote. I use this and the File tab is in the Desktop version. Try Repairing OneNote either from  Setup and Apps or from Control Panel, Programs and Features.

Comment: The linked instructions are only applicable. to the desktop version of OneNote. The default location for OneNote UWP application cannot be changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Desktop version of OneNote offers what you want.

You can install this by going to Microsoft Downloads for Office. Be sure you get the correct (32-bit vs 64-bit) version. I use 64-bit Office.

In the screen shot below, I show that I have my own personal location for OneNote files and this facilitates syncing with (backing up to) my other machine.

[image: One Note File location]